# Where put environment variables for Jenkins pipeline build (Best Practices)

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building some front-end project (Nuxt JS) on my deployment server(EC2) by Jenkins. For building those project we need lots of environment variable (S3 bucket info and other project specific variable). Those variables are also different based on branches like **staging server, development server, production server**.

So need to know where i put all those variables. I can declare variable as pipeline environment variable properties, but i think it's unsecure. Can i put variables on s3 and copy those file. Or put variable on deployment machine(EC2) as a separated file like .env.stage, .env.dev and inject those variables before build. I wants to know the procedure to injecting large amount off variables properly and securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-secret environment variables I would:

1. setup a **repository with all common variables among my projects** and loaded at build time.
   JSON databags were always my favorites.
2. setup **a configuration databag inside of each project that would bring only project specific and non-secret values**. this is also the correct place to override something defined in common.
3. at jenkins job level I can leave **some parameters to override databag / common values** but only non risy ones that control build behaviour (eg: build only - do not publish)
4. use **Jenkins credentials** if you have a small number of sensitive configs or (better) use **Hashicorp Vault** (free) to integrate with JK for secret management. Hashicorp is pretty complex , so don't use it unless you have to deal with a big number of configurations or you need t delegate the maintenance.
5. for anything that is not a configuration, **the shared libraries** should offer you a good place

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:
1) All credentials to credentials plugin
2) All variables/configuration to shared libraries.

Comment: thanks, it's great if you tell me details about 2. All variables/configuration to shared libraries this.